# How would one rotate an image around itself using Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm having trouble roating an image around itself using Canvas.

Since you can't rotate an image you have to rotate the canvas: if I rotate the canvas by a degree the origin around which I want to rotate changes. I don't get how to track this change.

This is my current code: http://pastie.org/669023

And a demo is at http://preview.netlashproject.be/cog/

If you want to give things a shot the zipped up code and image is at http://preview.netlashproject.be/cog/cog.zip

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I fixed your code:

```
var rotation = 0;
function draw(){

  var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';

  ctx.save();
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,200,200);
  ctx.translate(100,100); // to get it in the origin
  rotation +=1;
  ctx.rotate(rotation*Math.PI/64); //rotate in origin
  ctx.translate(-100,-100); //put it back
  ctx.drawImage(cog,0,0);
  ctx.restore();
}
```

The important thing here is that you have to translate the image to the origin first before rotating, and translate it back!

Answer (score 1):

it looks like this could be something you could use: http://wilq32.googlepages.com/wilq32.rollimage222

here's a test of it: http://www.antiyes.com/test/index.php

Comment: I'd like to use code that I actually understand and keep it simple.

Comment: you could have a look at the plugin code and see how it's done.

Comment: I know, I did. It seems to me there is a much simpler way using only canvas.

Comment: starting around line 308 there are about 6 or 7 lines of code that rotates the image with a canvas.  it looks pretty simple, the key is to translate it before rotating.